# KubeMQ open source for kubernetes / AMQP

Tags: kubernetes

Is there an option to use KubeMQ open source?

I see there was a commercial version but is there a similar open source option for kubernetes?

Sources

- [compare-kubemq](https://kubemq.io/compare-kubemq/)
- [kubemq blog](https://kubemq.io/blog/)

Answer (score 1):

I think they have an open-source edition now with Apache 2.0 license

> KubeMQ Community is the open-source version of KubeMQ, the Kubernetes native message broker.

as per [their GitHub](https://github.com/kubemq-io/kubemq-community/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: ok dear thanks, hope the edited answer is Ok now

Answer (score 0):

As you've already done some research I can confirm that KubeMQ is a paid solution and it's not possible to use it for free for production usage (it's possible though to have for development purposes for half a year - license details can be found [here](https://kubemq.io/product-pricing/))

There are good alternatives you can focus on:

- RabbitMQ - robust and very reliable solution ([here's how to run it in kubernetes](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2020/08/10/deploying-rabbitmq-to-kubernetes-whats-involved))
- Apache ActiveMQ

Answer (score 0):

they have an open-source docker image but most features regarding distributed processing, no kubernetes as orchestration platform, some UI features, etc. are missing in community. So for running KubeMQ in production you need to license the software. Just contact them, they are really quick actually.

However I have no hands on experience yet with enterprise ...